# onHover not working with scenegraph in deck.gl

Tags: node.js, gltf, onhover, scenegraph, deck.gl

my code - layer

```
new ScenegraphLayer({
  id:"22",
  scenegraph: "glb/22.glb",
  data: dataArray.glb22,
  getPosition: d => [d.geometry.coordinates[0],
                     d.geometry.coordinates[1], 0] ,
  sizeMinPixels: 1,
  sizeMaxPixels: 10,
  getOrientation: [0, 180, 90],
  getTranslation: [0, 0, 0],
  sizeUnits: 'meters',
  onHover: this._onHover
});
```

onHover Code is

```
_onHover({x, y, object}) {
  console.log("TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT");
}
```

but not working. this code working in geojsonLayer.

how to fix my code? I want onHover working in scenegraph-layer.
thanks.

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to add pickable ability? `onHover` requires pickable to be true.

Comment: oh.. you are alright. thanks. code is working!!!!!!

Comment: Let me add this as answer so you can accept it.

Comment: @kimyoungchan how did you manage to import a local glb file?

Comment: @dayz "scenegraph:local glb file path"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just forgot to add pickable ability. `onHover` required pickable properties to be true. You can read more about that [here](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/core/layer#onhover).

[Here](https://deck.gl/examples/scenegraph-layer/) there is an online example of ScenegraphLayer from official documentantion and [here](https://github.com/visgl/deck.gl/blob/master/examples/website/scenegraph/app.js) you can see the source code. Pay attention to [row 116](https://github.com/visgl/deck.gl/blob/d9c2f34847c1a950609a2e5480a34e42807e8eed/examples/website/scenegraph/app.js#L116):

```
const layer =
    data &&
    new ScenegraphLayer({
      id: 'scenegraph-layer',
      data,
      pickable: true,
      ...
    });
```